# Replacing poor performing cursor in SQL

Tags: sql, database, hana

I've wrote a sql statement using cursor but unfortunately the performance is pretty poor.
The data set that I'm running it on is about 8m records.

The cursor using table with some regex expressions (around 100) to try to extract parts from the column data itself.

```
FOR cur_row AS r_cursor(x) 
    DO
       SELECT SUBSTR_REGEXPR(cur_row.REGEX_PATTERN IN im_str GROUP cur_row.REGEX_GROUP) INTO col_part FROM DUMMY;
       
        IF :col_part IS NOT NULL THEN
            SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(col_part)) FROM DUMMY; //some more assignments go there 
            BREAK;
        ELSE
            col_part = im_str;
        END IF;
    END FOR;
```

Unfortunately for those 8m records this take over 40min.
Does anyone have any idea how can I rewrite it? (I'm using SAP HANA)

Comment: Would you be able to add sample input and desired output data in tabular text format on the question?

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.  The fastest cursor is the one that doesn't exist.

Comment: Why do you use cursor for this? Is there any non-trivial calculations inbetween? If no then just write select from select with CASE expression.
For extraction of groups you can use loop from 1 to max group to immitate recursive SQL and in each step select the desired group (without cursor again).

Comment: @astentx That cursor is based on the table that have over 250 regexes so unfortunately CASE with 250 WHENs is not the approach I can go with ...

Comment: @Mati I've thought that you've used a cursor for your test dataset also and the bottleneck was there. Because I cannot see all your code I doubt that the problem can be solved just by tuning since it's not the most common task for RDBMS. If you have the ability, try to parallelize the execution of regex into different background tasks. Also you can attach an R-server to HANA, create R procedure and let it do the parsing you want in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the reg ex for each row of the cursor, start with a smaller set of data of possible.  Make your data set as small as possible using an initial filter.

I don't know SAP HANA syntax, but in pseudocode:

select records into temptable where field contains search criteria

for each row in temptable
do something